# Why the json library isn't accepting my quotes?

Tags: python, json

I'm editing a json file with a Python script as follows:

`update-spec.py` file:

```
import os, sys, json


def update_json_file(url):
    full_path = os.path.abspath('services/swagger/swagger.json')
    with open(full_path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    data['servers'][0]['url'] = url
    with open(full_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        update_json_file(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        print('Please provide a URL')
        print('Usage:  python update-spec.py [url]')
        sys.exit()
```

when I run it with `python services/swagger/update-spec.py http://18.133.231.207` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "services/swagger/update-spec.py", line 16, in <module>
    update_json_file(sys.argv[1])
  File "services/swagger/update-spec.py", line 7, in update_json_file
    data = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 86 column 7
```

the json file:

```
 {
  "openapi": "3.0.2",
  "info": {
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "title": "Users Service",
    "description": "Swagger spec for documenting the users service"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/users/ping": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Just a sanity check",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Will return 'pong!'"
          }
        }
      }
    },
  "/users": {
    "get": {
      "summary": "Returns all users",
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "user object"
        }
      }
    },
    "post": {
      "summary": "Adds a new user",
      "requestBody": {
        "description": "User to add",
        "required": true,
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/user-full"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "security": [
        {
          "bearerAuth": []
        }
      ],
      "responses": {
        "201": {
          "description": "User added"
        },
        "401": {
          "description": "you don't have permission to do this"
        },
        "400": {
          "description": "invalid payload sent"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "/users/{id}": {
    "get": {
      "summary": "Returns a user based on id provided",
      "parameters": [
        {
        "name": "id",
        "in": "path",
        "description": "ID of user to fetch",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int64"
        }
      }
      ],
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "user object"
        },
        "404": {
          "description": "no user with that ID or no user added yet"
        },
      }
    }
  },
  "/auth/register": {
    "post": {
      "summary": "Creates a new user",
      "requestBody": {
        "description": "User to add",
        "required": true,
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/user-full"
                }
              }
            }
          },

      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "user object"
        },
        "400": {
          "description": "invalid payload sent"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "/auth/login": {
    "post": {
      "summary": "Logs a user in",
      "requestBody": {
        "description": "User to log in",
        "required": true,
        "content": {
          "application/json": {
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/user"
            }
          }
        }
    },
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Successfully logged in"
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "invalid payload sent"
      },
      "404": {
        "description": "no such user"
      },
      "500": {
        "description": "server error occured"
      }
    }
  }
  },
  "/auth/status": {
    "get": {
      "summary": "Returns the logged in user's status",
      "security": [
        {
          "bearerAuth": []
        }
      ],
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "user object"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "/auth/logout": {
    "get": {
      "summary": "Logs a user out",
      "security": [
        {
        "bearerAuth": []
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Successfully logged out"
      }
    }
    }
  }
  },
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "bearerAuth": {
        "type": "http",
        "scheme": "bearer"
      }
    },
    "schemas": {
      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "email": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "password": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "user-full": {
        "properties": {
          "username": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "password": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I've tried:

```
def update_json_file(url):
    full_path = os.path.abspath('services/swagger/swagger.json')
    with open(full_path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    data['servers'][0]['url'] = url
    with open(full_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        update_json_file(str(sys.argv[1]))   <--
    except IndexError:
        print('Please provide a URL')
        print('Usage:  python update-spec.py [url]')
        sys.exit()
```

and also:

```
def update_json_file(url):
    full_path = os.path.abspath('services/swagger/swagger.json')
    with open(full_path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    data['servers'][0]['url'] = "{}".format(url)  <--
    with open(full_path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        update_json_file(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        print('Please provide a URL')
        print('Usage:  python update-spec.py [url]')
        sys.exit()
```

Didn't work. Same error. What else I can try ?

Comment: Pretty hard to answer if you don't show us the problematic JSON. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris  I've added it to my question. In this particular case I didn't find it all that important to include it since I've not swapped double quotes for single quotes anywhere in the file.

Comment: Are you certain it's that part?   It looks ok.

Comment: Can you provide the full JSON? Your sample may be where the interpreter thinks the issue is, but it could be caused by a malformed portion prior to that, and trickled down. Having a fully reproducible example will make it much easier to assist you.

Comment: @ewong  Well, the file contains only one `"servers"` key.

Comment: @gallen  I've added it.

Comment: Thank you all of you for taking a look. This is really puzzling me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to an extra comma on the line before where the interpreter raises the error.

```
...
"404": {
    "description": "no user with that ID or no user added yet"
}, # <--- Remove this comma
...
```

Comment: I gotta say the error output was pretty misleading. I was focusing on quotes not on commas.

Comment: JSONDecode errors are usually due to malformed JSON. I approach these errors with the mindset of "what's wrong upstream from the decoder telling me this error?". Worked well for me so far.

Comment: Well it was a great learning experience for me too. Next time something similar happens I'm gonna double check punctuation too.